# How can I execute javascript in this PHP loop?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to generate random div widths for each database result that's output.

The code works when it's outside the loop, but every div is the same 'random' width.

- load page and all divs are 200px
- refresh page and all divs are 150px
- refresh page and all divs are 250px ...etc.

The trouble being, I need each individual div to be a random width, not all the same random width... for that reason I've added my javascript inside the loop in order to get a new 'random' width each time a database value is output.

And of course, it's not working!

```
<?php 
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from tbl_status ORDER BY tbl_status.date desc");

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                        <script>
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            var x = Math.floor((Math.random()*150)+150);
                            $('.statusCont').width(x+'px');
                        });
                        </script>

                        echo'
                    <div class="statusCont">
                        <div class="statusUsr">Tom Adams - Newcastle</div>
                        <div class="statusTxt"><p>' . $row['status'] . '</p></div>
                    </div><!-- ends .statusCont -->
                    ';}
            ?>
```

Comment: since PHP can't execute the JS script, maybe it should just `echo` it to the browser?

Comment: Can't you create a random number with PHP and set the width equal to that value?

Comment: It's possible but my knowledge is not so great.

Comment: do not include the jquery api with every iteration of the loop. It's a waste of bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that all the div's have the same random width is because the jquery class selector `$('.statusCont')` will return all elements with that class. So when your loop prints out the last selector it applies to all of the previous loaded elements.

Instead of including the javascript in the php `while` loop you can just write a script in the head that will affect the page after it's loaded

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.statusCont').each(function () {
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 150) + 150);
        $(this).width(x);
      });
 );
```